# Function argument sizes and gas usage

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, struct, calldata

Is there any penalty for the amount of data passed to a function? Asking because I see non-linear behavior in gas usage during testing when sending more than 31 items in the array.

```
struct Payment {
    uint256 amount;
    bytes32 salt;
    bytes32 authorClientHash;
    bytes32 payToHash;
    address author;
    address client;
    address payTo;
    bytes authorSig;
    bytes clientSig;
    bytes payToSig;
    bytes approvedSignerSig;
}

function batchPay(Payment[] calldata payments) external onlyApprovedSender nonReentrant { }
```

TIA!

Comment: How much is the gas variation? Are you doing something else? Transaction input data cost should be linear, memory cost are quadratic.